# django+mysql: breaking data based on months in different tables?

Tags: mysql, django

I have a web application which generates a large volume of `time-stamped` data something like log.

I would like to use RDBMS specifically MySQL for this task since my development team is comfortable with it.

Problem is when the data gets accumulated over time in the tables the SQL Query starts to eat too much of resources; so we thought of creating multiple tables at MySQL Database level which can act like small buckets to store data for a specific period of time say `month` or so; Now I would like to understand that how could I achieve this alongside working with `django` and least damaging its ORM fruits; so that our existing system has to be modified in minimal way.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? Which SQL query is eating all the resources? The INSERT or the SELECT? If the problem is at the SELECT, then maybe you should review the indices. Looks like you need some optimization. If not done, I'd start by optimizing your database. Maybe you need an index in the timestamp fields? Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index
EDIT: Fixed typo

Comment: @JuanXarg I am already using indexes indeed it is a performance booster but it won't solve the whole problem when you have to search and sort in large data.

Comment: IMHO, messing with Django ORM's default behaviour will be painful. Have you explored other DBMS optimization techniques? It looks like your case will be a good candidate for table partitioning. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html